# How to add weights parameter to Generalized Mixed Model

Tags: julia, mixed-models

How do you add the weight of an observation to a Mixed Model?
I thought I could add the Freq column to wt argument, but apparently not.

```
using RDatasets MixedModels
titanic = RDatasets.dataset("datasets", "Titanic")
titanic.surv_flg = titanic.Survived .== "Yes";
```

This runs:

```
MixedModels.fit(GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, @formula(surv_flg ~ 1 + Age + Sex + (1 | Class)), titanic, Bernoulli(), nAGQ = 2, fast = true)
```

But this doesn't

```
MixedModels.fit(GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, @formula(surv_flg ~ 1 + Age * Sex + (1 | Class)), titanic, wt = Freq, Bernoulli(), nAGQ = 2, fast = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this out on another forum.

the parameter should be `wts` not `wt`.

So it should be:
`MixedModels.fit(GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, @formula(surv_flg ~ 1 + Age * Sex + (1 | Class)), titanic, wts = Freq, Bernoulli(), nAGQ = 2)`